# Data Conversion in Spring

Tags: sql, spring-data-jpa

I am new to Spring here, When I use long data type (for storing timestamps)  it is converted to Medium Text in SQL and it is causing some problems in my code. Is there any solution to this?
ex:

```
@Column(columnDefinition = "long default 0")
private long loginfailedtime;

@Column(columnDefinition = "long default 0")
private long lastlogintime;

@Column(columnDefinition = "long default 0")
private long otp_timestamp;
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Aq87.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the value you want to store is time, I would recommend using Date type instance.

```
    @Column(columnDefinition="TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP")   
    private Date loginfailedtime;
    @Column(columnDefinition="TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP")   
    private Date lastlogintime;
    @Column(columnDefinition="TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP")   
    private Date otp_timestamp;
```

Also, if you want to use **long**, in column definition you are using long, where the data type corresponding to the table should be mentioned.

**columnDefinition** : The SQL fragment that is used when generating the DDL for the column.

For instance,

```
@Column(name="EMP_PIC", columnDefinition="BLOB NOT NULL")
```

In JAVA 8, we have below mappings provided.

```
@Column(name = "local_time", columnDefinition = "TIME")
private LocalTime localTime;
 
@Column(name = "local_date", columnDefinition = "DATE")
private LocalDate localDate;
 
@Column(name = "local_date_time", columnDefinition = "TIMESTAMP")
private LocalDateTime localDateTime;
```

Explore more here => https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-java-time

Comment: I am using BigInteger instead of long

Comment: Then you can add @Column(columnDefinition = "bigint(20)")